# What is the "Software Reporter Tool" downloaded by Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

After using Google Chrome for like about 10 minutes today, Symantec AV displayed a pop-up in the notification area with the text "software_reporter_tool.exe is safe".

I was not consciously downloading anything from the internet at the time and decided to take a look at the details of the notification. It turns out that Google Chrome had downloaded an 854Kb executable named "software_reporter_tool.exe":

[image]

I was not able to find much of any information on what this tool does.

Does it check what software I have installed and report that to Google?

Or something else?

Comment: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/bFhfVkR-ENo

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/978234/chrome-100-cpu-usage-again-software-reporter-tool-exe

Comment: Be wary with the accepted answer. This is NOT a safe file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from [this forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/bFhfVkR-ENo):

> Oh, I see - that is the .exe process for the software removal tool.
>   This is a safe file.
>
> You can simply remove the SRT app from your computer if you'd no
>   longer like to use it. However, it is the most affective way so far to
>   combat malicious redirection Malware in Chrome.
>
> 2. Norton, as with any other anti virus, will conflict with SRT. You should only have one anti virus program running at a time.
> 3. This depends on the application and greatly varies. For instance; Hangouts needs access to your mic and online status.
> 4. You can uninstall SRT with Windows add/remove programs.

Comment: The accepted answer in that link looks suspicious - they are asking what is the tool and a Google employee doesn't answer the question and just suggests to uninstall it from Control Panel (which is not possible as the application doesn't show up on the list)

Answer (score 4):

The link provided in @Anon 's answer is useful but doesn't really say much about why a web browser scans the user's hard drive in folders that have nothing to do with Chrome, and taking up CPU and battery resources in the process.

They provide a bit more detailed sentence [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/XCOGDETHNZs):

> It runs in the background checking for the malicious software and
>   alerting you to run the clean up tool to remove it

Still it doesn't give out much information about how and why that program is there or how to avoid having it scanning your hard drive. So I wouldn't consider it *safe*, only because it comes from the vendor.

Comment: I just installed Chrome and made sure to uncheck the box that said to send usage to Google, then it still stressed my NVME to 90 degree celsius: https://superuser.com/questions/1651916/google-chrome-software-reporter-tool-stressing-cpu-and-heating-ssd

Answer (score 2):

Uninstalling or deleting or renaming the file will not work because it will simply come back when Chrome is updated.  But it can easily be disabled as shown in the following link...

http://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-google-chrome-software-reporter-tool

Comment: Welcome to Super User! External links can break or be unavailable, in which case your answer would not be useful.  Please include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.