# Google Chrome software reporter tool stressing CPU and heating SSD

Tags: google-chrome, security, browser, privacy, metadata

I just installed Google chrome, when downloading, I made sure to **uncheck the checkbox that said to send usage data to Google**.
Now after using it for a bit, I see computer going nuts, **NVME SSD got to 90 degrees Celsius** (!).
In task manager I see Google Chrome with most CPU and power usage, expanding it shows that it is "**Software reporting tool**" from Google that is **stressing my computer** to extreme.
This goes away after some minutes after it does its thing, but ...

**Why** does the software reporting tool have so much activity when I do not want to send any data ?
To me it shows that it is still looking trough my data and most probably sending it to ~Google.

Comment: & what other thing compelled you to trust an app by a company whose entire business model is to sell advertising, based on your habits, a browser which a user would ordinarily allow straight through their firewall unhindered… ;)

Comment: I keep thinking about this and I have zero reasons to use Chrome over Mozilla :) Will think some more :)

Comment: Chromium is an option too